# Static_cast or c style typecast

Tags: int, static-typing

I want to extract the integer part of a double number without using `modf`.
Which is better to do it `static_cast<int>(x)` or `(int)x`?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood for primitive types they are both exactly the same. If you are just assigning it to an int variable you don't even need the cast since it will automatically be converted. I think it is just a matter of preference.  I perfer the c-style casts for primitives `(int)x` whereas I use static_cast and dynamic_cast, etc for C++ class types where you need to deal with things like inheritance.

Note that this behavior may be inconsistent for dealing with negative numbers depending on your compiler or system ie -6.4 could be truncated to -6 or pushed down to -7.